# How to create a website with my IP address

Tags: ip, router

Xfinity is my ISP. I would like to be able to (occasionally) access my home network while away from home. I know how to configure the router etc., but the issue is this: I do not have a static IP, and without the router's current IP address, I cannot connect with it. My question is this: Is there some way to build a website that shows the current IP address? Note that this does not have to be up-to-the-second accurate - I could possibly write something to update the site say on a daily basis.

Comment: you need a domain name, IPs are dynamic usually

Comment: I kinda thought that, but when I logged into afraid.org from out-of-the-house, I didn't see any domains, etc. However, I just logged in from home, I saw my URL with the current IP address. Thanks - your answer is correct.